# Error in merging 2 LINQ lists

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having issues after merging 2 LINQ lists.  I get the following error: the query contains reference to items defined on a different data context.

This is how I constructed my final 2 LINQ lists:

```
CAPDBDataContext CAdb = new CAPDBDataContext();
USPDBDataContext USdb = new USPDBDataContext();

var ExceptionList = Special_texts.Where(x => x.name.Equals("ExceptionList"))
                    .Select(x => x.special_text1)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    .SelectMany(x => x)
                    .ToList();

var USquery = from uscomp in USdb.UScompanies
              join ussect in USdb.USsectors
              on uscomp.sector_code equals ussect.sector_code
              select new
              {
                  uscomp.company_name,
                  uscomp.primary_exchange,
                  ussect.description
              };

var CAtemp = from x in CAdb.companies
             where !ShefalisList.Contains(x.ticker)
             select x;

var CAquery = from temp in CAtemp
             join casect in CAdb.sectors
             on temp.sector_code equals casect.sector_code
             select new
             {                          
                 temp.company_name,
                 temp.primary_exchange,                             
                 casect.description
             };

 var mergedList = USquery.Union(CAquery).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
var mergedList = USquery.AsEnumerable().Union(CAquery).ToList()
```

You can't `Union` queries over different databases without getting their results into memory.

Comment: +1: I would recommend using `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()` (for the first section - no need to build the list here), which will also make the second `AsEnumerable()` call unneeded...

Comment: @ReedCopsey are you referring to the code 'var ExceptionList = '? for (1st section).  Then are you suggesting that the mergedlist should look like 'var mergedList = USquery.Union(CAquery).ToList()'?

Comment: I created a CSVExtension class but I can't seem to get the list enumerations from the merge.  I created it like 'public static class CSVExtensions
    {
        public static void WriteToCSVFile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> mergedList)'.  Isn't this right?

Comment: @inquisitive_one "I can't seem to get the list enumerations from the merge." – this problem description is too vague. It also sounds like a new problem, you should make a new proper question with the current state of your code.